# Using chosen.js to let user add the options not in the list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to use `http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/` lib to make nice lists of items for my users to choose.

The way it works is that it converts a list into an input field, where user can simply enter a value and if it exists in the list of options, it'll be added as a kind of tag in the list.

What I want to do, however, is if the user types something in that does not exist, they can add it as a new option into the list.

Is it possible using `chosen` or maybe you know of a better solution?

Basically it should work a bit like StackOverflow's Tags field - you type something in, if it exists, it's selected. If not – something new is added.

Comment: There are plugins that do this, but chosen doesn't have this option by default

Comment: What about this? It's close I think. http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager